# Fedora 389 ds sasl mapping issue?

Tags: centos, kerberos, sasl, 389-ds, sssd

I have a fedora client that is authenticating to a centos server running 389 ds and kerberos

I can run `kinit <my-user-principal>` on the fedora client successfully and get a ticket, but no matter what I try I just cannot authenticate with kerberos to the 389 server.

whenever I try `ldapwhoami -I -Y GSSAPI` I get the following error:

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL Interaction
Please enter your authorization name: test@LAB2.LOCAL
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Unknown error)
```

Doing a klist I can see I have my tickets:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: test@LAB2.LOCAL

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
01/09/13 00:26:58  01/10/13 00:26:58  krbtgt/LAB2.LOCAL@LAB2.LOCAL
    renew until 01/09/13 00:26:58
01/09/13 00:27:45  01/10/13 00:26:58  ldap/dp100srv1.lab2.local@LAB2.LOCAL
    renew until 01/09/13 00:26:58
```

I edited the nsslapd-accesslog-level attribute of cn=config to be 260 and when I checked the access log I found this (172.16.86.200 is the IP of my fedora client):

```
tail -n 15 /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-dp100srv1/access
[09/Jan/2013:00:58:13 -0500] conn=130 fd=64 slot=64 connection from 172.16.86.200 to 172.16.86.100
[09/Jan/2013:00:58:16 -0500] conn=130 op=0 BIND dn="" method=sasl version=3 mech=GSSAPI
[09/Jan/2013:00:58:16 -0500] conn=130 op=0 RESULT err=49 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0
[09/Jan/2013:00:58:16 -0500] conn=130 op=1 UNBIND
[09/Jan/2013:00:58:16 -0500] conn=130 op=1 fd=64 closed - U1
```

What is BIND dn="" about? That can't be right, but according to the 389 docs the default sasl maps that are already configured should be enough for my purposes.

Where else can I look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you miss somewhere configuration that tell sasl what is the default DN.

try to add to /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[domain/default]
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
```

And as a `dc=example,dc=com`, I mean base DN of your LDAP